# Unable to connect to MariaDB on Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I have the following docker-compose-yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wp_db
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - my_network

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.7.8
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp_db
      MYSQL_USER: wp_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER: 1
      MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_GRANTS: "RELOAD, PROCESS, LOCK TABLES, BINLOG MONITOR"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./datadir:/var/lib/mysql
      - backup:/backup
    networks:
      - my_network

volumes:
  backup:

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

This works fine as is. The site is running and using the DB.

When I run the command:

```
docker compose run db mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/backup
```

I get the following:

```
[00] 2023-03-18 16:32:15 Connecting to MariaDB server host: localhost, user: not set, password: not set, port: not set, socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[00] 2023-03-18 16:32:15 Failed to connect to MariaDB server: Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory").
```

I'm not sure why the socket is defined as it is. I would have thought this should be '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: When you run `mariabackup`, how does it find the location of the database server?  It's in its own container so it won't be `localhost` or a Unix socket.

Comment: I'm a bit green around the gills when it comes to this but I'm executing the command on the same container, so wouldn't it be right to try and connect to locahost? At least internally, that's what I would understand how it sees itself?

Comment: `docker-compose run` starts a new container, but that's probably what you want.

Comment: `docker exec` is better I think as per response below. I just want to run that command on the container instance rather than start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) for getting backup in a container:

```bash
docker run --user mysql -v some-mariadb-socket:/var/run/mysqld -v some-mariadb-backup:/backup -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql --rm mariadb:latest mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/backup
```

As we have a socket problem and if you want to use `compose`, try to add the new socket volume in the db service:

```yaml
volumes:
      - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./datadir:/var/lib/mysql
      - backup:/backup
      - some-mariadb-socket:/var/run/mysqld
```

and add the `some-mariadb-socket` to the `volumes`:

```yaml
volumes:
  backup:
  some-mariadb-socket:
```

Try:

```bash
docker compose exec db mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/backup
```

Then `exec` instead of `run`.

Comment: No joy. Same result. Destroyed volumes also to make sure.

Comment: Should not you specify user, pass? `mariabackup --backup \
   --target-dir=/var/mariadb/backup/ \
   --user=mariabackup --password=mypassword`?

Comment: Quite possibly but I'm getting an error about not being able to connect. If it was credentials issue, I'd see an error regarding that.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try again and let me know if it helped or if the error has been changed.